# Customizing Adapter in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I'm trying to complete a code that controls a custom ListView through three classes: `AdapterListView`, `ItemListView` and `MainActivity`.

So far, the code can only enter **data** and **images** (inserted by code) through `AdapterListView`.

I added in my `item_list.xml` two buttons, a button to **remove** the item from the list and another button to **edit** the list item.

I tried to implement the method to remove the item and insert in my `AdapterListView` but I did not know how to call it in `MainActivity`.

```
    public void deletaItem(View v) {
    adapterListView.removeItem(?????);
    }
```

I also need to know how do I **edit** the item after clicking on the edit button.

**Below the three project classes:**

**AdapterListView**

```
package com.example.aulasandroid.aulas_android_listviewactions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by lmontanhine on 11/2/2015.
*/
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

/**
 * Retorna a quantidade de itens
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

/**
 * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public ItemListView getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

/**
 * Sem implementação
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Pega o item de acordo com a posção.
    ItemListView item = itens.get(position);
    //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    //atraves do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
    //ao item e definimos as informações.
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());

    return view;
}
public void removeItem(int positionToRemove){
    itens.remove(positionToRemove);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**ItemListView**

```
package com.example.aulasandroid.aulas_android_listviewactions;

/**
* Created by lmontanhine on 11/2/2015.
*/
public class ItemListView {

private String texto;
private int iconeRid;

public ItemListView() {
}

public ItemListView(String texto, int iconeRid) {
    this.texto = texto;
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public int getIconeRid() {
    return iconeRid;
}

public void setIconeRid(int iconeRid) {
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.aulasandroid.aulas_android_listviewactions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private AdapterListView adapterListView;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Pega a referencia do ListView
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //Define o Listener quando alguem clicar no item.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    createListView();
}

private void createListView() {
    //Criamos nossa lista que preenchera o ListView
    itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();
    ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Felpudo", R.drawable.felpudo);
    ItemListView item2 = new ItemListView("Felpudão", R.drawable.felpudo1);
    ItemListView item3 = new ItemListView("Felpudinho", R.drawable.felpudo2);

    itens.add(item1);
    itens.add(item2);
    itens.add(item3);

    //Cria o adapter
    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    //Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    //Cor quando a lista é selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);
    //Demostração
    Toast.makeText(this, "Você Clicou em: " + item.getTexto(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void deletaItem(View v) {
    adapterListView.removeItem();
}
}
```

**item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5sp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Editar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Deletar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="deletaItem"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the getView method, you can set a tag to each delete button, something like:

```
((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete)).setTag(position);
```

(position is the first param of getView inside the adapter).

then, in the deletaItem method, you can ask for v.getTag(), and this value will be the param for removeItem.

```
public void deletaItem(View v) {
    adapterListView.removeItem(v.getTag());
}
```

EDIT: is pretty much the same.

inside adapter's `getView`:

```
((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit)).setTag(position);
```

inside adapter class, create a new method, something like:

```
public void editItem(int position) {
    // edit behavior
    .
    .
    .
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

inside activity:

```
public void onClickEditButton(View v) {
    adapterListView.editItem(v.getTag());
}
```

also, don't forget to add onClick="onClickEditButton" on item_list.xml

hope it helps :D

EDIT 2: to edit the item text

```
 public void editItem(int position) {
    getItem(position).setTexto("new text");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: thanks for reply! How can I implement the method to edit the item at another button I created? I need to create the Adapter and call the same way in ActivityView. @Matias Elorriaga's

Comment: Sorry about that, my ponte didn't load the entire answare! Tks@MatiasElorriaga

Comment: Please, do you know what i need put inside method editItem? @MatiasElorriaga

Comment: that depends on what you want to achieve.. maybe update some data in the "model" (ItemListView)..

Comment: In this case, i want to change a name of item. @MatiasElorriaga